# LibGDX / Android: Playing sound effects makes the game stutter - Sound.play() takes 4 ms on a high-end device

Tags: android, performance, audio, libgdx

Whenever I play a sound effect in my LibGDX game on an Android device, the game stutters. I have tried the game on three Samsung devices:

- On Galaxy S7 Edge (2016, Android 8) and Galaxy Tab S 10.5 (2014, Android 6.0.1) the game is still playable, but not running smoothly whenever there are multiple sound effects being played (looping a sound effects are not a problem).
- However on Galaxy S20 Ultra (2020, Android 10) the game is unplayable: **Every call to Sound.play() takes 2...4 ms and causes "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount 0 -> 54276" error.** This error does not appear with the other devices, but Sound.play() still takes 1...2 ms which of course is a considerable portion of a 16 ms frame.

**So what I think is pretty clear is that the problem is in the Sound.play() method**, not for example the number of concurrent sounds playing (which I have limited to 8 but have tried 4 as well), or that the Android device would be too slow to process the sounds (in which case a 6 year old GT should not outperform this year's high-end S20), or that the sound effect files would be too large (the one I'm using for testing was originally a 3.8 kB WAV). And yes, I am using AssetManager to load the sounds in advance.

I have now spent two long days doing research, **found about 15-20 topics on different forums about what I believe is the same or related issue, and tried out all the suggested fixes without any success:**

- Changing audio format from WAV to OGG
- Different sample rates: 44.1k, 48k, 96k on both formats (with 96k, there is no stutter and no error, but no audible sound either)
- Adding silence of 1 or 2 seconds to the end of the sound effect (which itself is 41 ms long), with all the combinations of the above formats and sample rates.
- Some say that looping a silent sound clip "in background" has solved the problem, but I anyway have another sound (car engine) looping constantly in the game and that seems to have no effect.

I have also seen suggestions to use Music class instead of Sound, but it's not suitable for collision sound effects with Box2D because pitch cannot be adjusted.

The only workaround that I found but have not tried yet is playing the sounds on a different thread. I have not tried it because I'm not familiar with multithreading and have not been able to find a comprehensive enough guide on how to do it (properly) in LibGDX. I also assume that this approach would be problematic for any sounds which may have to be paused, stopped or adjusted during playback by some actor from the main thread. Furthermore, according to https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading, "You should never perform multi-threaded operations on anything that is graphics or audio related".

Therefore, before I even start familiarizing my self on that topic (multithreading), I just wanted to ask once more: Is there really no other solution? It just doesn't feel right that a high-end Android device from this year cannot start the playback of a small WAV sound any faster than in 4 ms. There are lot of games in Play store with working sound effects and smooth gameplay, are they all really using multithreading?

Comment: You might find this merged PR interesting. It got merged before the latest libGDX release  1.9.12. You can swap out the audio backend to use an asynchronous one that should improve this issue. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/6243

Comment: Yes, that was very interesting! Couldn't use it as such due to no Sound ID support, but by using it as a template I was able to create my own solution where all the Sounds are played and modified on a separate HandlerThread on Android devices. The game runs perfectly smoothly now on all test devices, and at least so far I have not encountered any problems caused by sounds being played on separate thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but I'll share some ideas here.

My own anecdotal experience is that sound operations such as starting sound playback tend to be too time-consuming for a typical render thread on Android. I've tried a few different approaches (`AudioTrack`, `SoundPool`, etc.), and as best I can remember have gotten similar results in each case.

Putting the audio on a different thread seems like the most practical solution. I understand the hesitance if you're not familiar with multithreading, and I think you're right to be cautious, especially when using a third-party library. However, for simple tasks, Android supplies some fairly straightforward tools, like `HandlerThread` and `Handler`, that could perhaps be leveraged.

As for the LibGDX documentation saying not to perform multi-threaded operations on anything audio related, it's not clear to me whether that means don't do anything audio-related on a thread other than the render thread, or if it just means to keep all audio on a single thread, but that that thread doesn't have to be the render thread. If it's the latter, then putting audio on a separate thread might be an option.

I took a quick look at the LibGDX source code. I'd have to spend more time to better understand what's going on, but I see use of both `AudioTrack` and `SoundPool`, and I'm pretty sure I've run into this issue with both.

But, I also see some signs of asynchronous sound functionality. There are some classes with 'asynchronous' in the name that use a dedicated handler thread. I don't know if this functionality is documented (I couldn't find the documentation immediately) or otherwise supported, but it does seem to be present in the source code. The comments say there are some limitations, but it's not immediately clear to me what they are.

As for communication between the render thread and an audio thread, it would add some complexity, but you should be able to do it fairly straightforwardly using handlers or other similar tools. In fact, that's what the LibGDX code I looked at does - it creates a `HandlerThread` and uses a `Handler` (naturally) to post to it. It can still be difficult, especially when using a third-party library where you don't control where all audio operations occur. For example, LibGDX may always set up the audio objects on a specific thread (e.g. the render thread), which means if you use another thread, you'll be using the objects on a thread other than that on which they were created. I doubt that would be an issue, but it depends on the technology. (For example, the documentation for ExoPlayer says that instances should only be used from a single thread.)

In my own code I'm doing all audio myself, so I control it and can put everything on the same thread. That might be difficult or impossible with LibGDX, but the presence of the 'asynchronous' audio classes may be a hint that playing audio on a different thread is safe to do. (And maybe you can make use of those classes, assuming they're a supported part of the API.)

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer! I managed to use HandlerThread to successfully play and modify the sounds, as described on my other comment above. It indeed looks like playing the sounds on a separate thread is the only viable solution at the moment, and it was not so difficult to implement after all.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this issue. In your AndroidLauncher, override this.

```
@Override
public AndroidAudio createAudio(Context context, AndroidApplicationConfiguration config) {
    return new AsynchronousAndroidAudio(context, config);
}
```

You **MUST** make sure you don't have any SoundId actions (eg. `some_sound.Stop(sound_id)`). As those will not work with `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` and will crash the game. So check that before you publish your game.